# Table Column Value Calculations thru Groovy Scripting

Tags: groovy

At the outset, let me confess that I am a newbie to Groovy Script but have prior scripting experience in other languages.

I am trying to calculate a sum of field values entered by users in a web form based on an Oracle Table. This Table has approx 5 sections with about 5 questions in each section. Each question has a drop down list like Yes, No & N/A. All the questions (read Table Columns) in each section are named like SEC_1_Q1, SEC_1_Q2,.... SEC_2_Q1,SEC_2_Q2,.... etc.

Depending upon the value (Yes, No, N/A) a user picks a score (1,2,0) is assigned to the corresponding question. Each section has its own total ( which becomes a sub-total for the entire table, so there will be 5 sub-totals) and a Grand Total - which is a sum of all the section totals. All the subtotals and the Grand total are visible to the users and are updated OnItemChange for any question.

This is how I visualize creating a script for this

First go thru the Column Names matching an expression and create an array or some kind of list and get the user provided Values , sum them up and update the sub-totals and the grand total so a user can see them.

This will avoid hard coding the Column Names and will also provide future room for including/excluding  questions from the current sections.

I have looked hard and searched on the web, but haven't come across any ideas for Groovy Scripting.

I am sure there are many other great options to achieve this thru Java and other languages, but my choice right now is limited to Groovy.

I was wondering if any/all good souls out there can point me to the right direction(s). Any cooked, half-cooked Groovy script examples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so you want to query an existing db table? it's not clear

Comment: @tim_yates : Most often the table will be rendered thru a web application to a user to create a NEW form, there may be instances where a user might modify previouly filled forms. In both situation, I would like to calculate the sub-total & the grand total based on the modified values dynamically OnItemChange not before a Save event.

Comment: i'm having some trouble parsing this. If you have a pre-existing db table, could you post the relevant CREATE TABLE statement?  Also, unclear what OnItemChange vs. Save events are - are these in reference to some browser-side javascript framework you're using?  and how is groovy fitting into this - GSP in grails?  groovelet?

Comment: so you want one thing in groovy that will work on a db table and also in the browser through some sort of JavaScript backed mechanism?

Comment: @ tim_yates: let me try to explain it better:

Comment: @tim_yates: Sorry-hit enter too soon. OnItemChange is a groovy script I want to add to the fields to be modified by users and when a value in that field changes, the script runs and updates the sub-totals/totals. Save event refers to when user hits the Save button ( after answering/modifying some/all of the questions. CREATE TABLE may not be applicable in this situation as we already are rendering the underlying Table thru a web app (like a form). The completed forms are creating data records in that very underlying table. I am hoping to this all in Groovy without introducing JavaScript.